# Send Integer value over TCP from Java to C#

Tags: java, c#, tcpclient

I am trying to send an integer value from a java program to my c# program, for some reason the received byte[] is always empty?

Java Write Code:

```
public void SendData(List<List<String>> tooltips){
    try {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonData = gson.toJson(tooltips);

        byte[] dataBytes = jsonData.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        int totalBytes = dataBytes.length;

        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(this.outputStream);
        dos.writeInt(totalBytes);
        dos.flush();

        // Send the data using the output stream
        this.outputStream.write(dataBytes);
        this.outputStream.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

C# Receive Code:

```
public static List<List<string>> ReceiveListOfLists(TcpClient client)
{
    try
    {
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

        byte[] lengthBuffer = new byte[4];
        stream.Read(lengthBuffer, 0, lengthBuffer.Length);
        int dataLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(lengthBuffer, 0);

        // Read the data bytes
        byte[] dataBytes = new byte[dataLength];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while (bytesRead < dataLength)
        {
            bytesRead += stream.Read(dataBytes, bytesRead, dataLength - bytesRead);
        }

        var jsonData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataBytes);

        // Deserialize the JSON data into a List of Lists of strings
        var tooltips = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<string>>>(jsonData);
        return tooltips;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

This is how I establish the connection:

Java Connect:

```
public SocketSender(String serverAddress, int serverPort) {
    this.serverAddress = serverAddress;
    this.serverPort = serverPort;
    try {
        this.socket = new Socket(this.serverAddress, this.serverPort);
        this.outputStream = this.socket.getOutputStream();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

C# Connect:

```
public class SocketManager
{
    private Socket clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    private TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 5020);
    private TcpClient client;
    public SocketManager() 
    {
        tcpListener.Start();
        client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
    }
    public List<List<string>> GetListOfStringList()
    {           
        return SocketReceiver.ReceiveListOfLists(client);
    }
}
```

I have also tried receiving the data with a Binary Reader like this:

```
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
int dataSize = reader.ReadInt32();
```

But the integer still resulted in 0.

Comment: i noticed adding this before the getStream on the C# Side fixes the problem, but why can I only get the Stream when Data is available?
do
                {

                } while (client.Available == 0);

                var stream = client.GetStream();

Comment: Do you mean `this.client.getStream()` instead of `client.getStream()`? If so, can you please show the whole class containing `ReceiveListOfLists`?

Comment: Also note that methods _in Java_ should be camelCase by convention.

Comment: I was not referring to the keyword `this` i was referring to this code i added:
`do 
{

 } while (client.Available == 0); 
var stream = client.GetStream();`

Comment: Do you have some special reason why you want to use raw TCP? There are higher level protocols and libraries that allow you to send *messages* instead of having to mess around with streams, message framings etc. These will likely be easier to use and more reliable. I found MQTT fairly easy to get started with, but there are plenty of good alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

> `stream.Read(lengthBuffer, 0, lengthBuffer.Length);`

Yet another case of "check your return values". [`Stream.Read`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.read?view=net-7.0) can, and I quote the official documentation here, "be less than the number of bytes allocated in the buffer if that many bytes are not currently available".

You want to put that in a loop until you read the number of bytes you want (in your case 4 bytes). This applies to every single kind of stream in C#, and it will bite you in the ass the most with sockets and compression streams.